# Autofac - Resolve Specific Implementation in Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac

I have a class hierarchy that goes something like this

```
interface IDbHelper{
    //some functions
}

class dbHelper: IDbHelper{
    private readonly **AppContext**
    //call db functions
}

interface IService{
    private readonly idbHelper;
}

class Service: IService{
    private readonly IdbHelper
    //call db functions
}

Interface IApp{
    //do some functions

}

class App1: IApp{
    private readonly IService;
}


class App2: IApp{
    private readonly IService;
}
```

So here is a simple structure of classes that are being used I have an IApp interface that has 2 implementations, **App1** and **App2**, each of these classes uses the same implementation of **Service** and the service in turn uses implementation of DBHelper, which uses the AppContext.

The app context varies depending on the App being used.

The Each of the classes are registered with autofac container like

```
builder.RegisterType<App1>().As<IApp>();
builder.RegisterType<App2>().As<IApp>();
builder.RegisterType<Service>().As<IService>();
builder.RegisterType<DBHelper>().As<IDBHelper>();
```

Each of the required classes by the Apps, services, and helpers are Injected via constructor. And I want the same functionality in case of AppContext, such that when resolving dependancies Context for the specific App is created rather than a single one. For example, I want the context for App1 to be used in DBHelper when App1 is resolved, and Context for App2 to be used with App2 is resolved.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: [Have you read the docs?](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html)

Comment: I did read the docs but i couldnt quite understand how to solvs this issue.